# Extract all but the first character in batch?

Tags: batch-file

To extract the first character ONLY I would use:

```
%var:~0,1%
```

To extract the last character ONLY I would use:

```
%var:~0,-1%
```

So how would I extract all except the first character?

I tried looking in "set /?" under cmd prompt but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract from a specific character to the end of the string, only specify the starting index:

```
%var:~1%
```

This is covered in `set /?` but it's buried inside a paragraph and definitely not easy to find:

---

May also specify substrings for an expansion.

```
%PATH:~10,5%
```

would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
result.  **If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
remainder of the variable value.**  If either number (offset or length) is
negative, then the number used is the length of the environment variable
value added to the offset or length specified.

---

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that :)